# PDF download by angular 5

Tags: angular, base64, angular5

I'm using angular 5.how to make a download link or pdf viewer from base64 string.

I have tried

```
<input name="file2" type="file" [(ngModel)]="myfile" base-sixty-four-input >
```

And in TypeScript class

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test2';
  myfile = {
    filetype: "application/pdf",
    filename: "test.pdf",
    base64: 'JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFuZyhlbi1HQikgL1N0cnVjdFRyZWVSb290IDEwIDAgUi9NYXJrSW5mbzw8L01hcmtlZCB0cnVlPj4
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a link like

```
<a [href]="downloadLink">Download {{ myfile.filename }}</a>
```

And in your class,

```
//First import
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// Then
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

myfile = {
    filetype: "octet-stream;base64",
    filename: "test.pdf",
    base64:  'JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFuZyhlbi1HQikgL1N0cnVjdFRyZWVSb290IDEwIDAgUi9NYXJrSW5mbzw8L01hcmtlZCB0cnVlPj4'
};

downloadLink = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(`data:${this.myfile.filetype},${this.myfile.base64}`);
```

Comment: when click on link sys : unsafe:data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUNCi

Answer (score 0):

Add the below filetype in app.component

```
filetype: application/octet-stream;base64
```